# Python pass by variable in function not working

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing an program in python that takes an infix ecuation and transform it into an postfix ecuation (polish notation) , then it evaluates it. The problem comes when i pass a string to the function infixToPostfix (if i pass it a string like "2 + 3 * 5" it run perfect, but if i pass it a string variable it explode)

```
class StackClass:

    def __init__(self, itemlist=[]):
        self.items = itemlist

    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.items == []:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[-1:][0]

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
    return 0

def parse_rpn(expression):
    stack = []

    for val in expression.split(' '):
        if val in ['-', '+', '*', '/', '^']:
            op1 = stack.pop()
            op2 = stack.pop()
            if val == '-': result = op2 - op1
            if val == '+': result = op2 + op1
            if val == '*': result = op2 * op1
            if val == '/': result = op2 / op1
            if val == '^': result = op2** op1
            stack.append(result)
        else:
            stack.append(float(val))

    return stack.pop()

def infixToPostfix(infixexpr):
    prec = {}
    prec['^'] = 3
    prec['*'] = 2
    prec['/'] = 2
    prec['+'] = 1
    prec['-'] = 1
    opStack = StackClass()
    postfixList = []
    tokenList = infixexpr.split()

    for token in tokenList:
        if token in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" or token in "0123456789":
            postfixList.append(token)
        else:
            while (not opStack.isEmpty()) and \
                (prec[opStack.peek()] >= prec[token]):
                    postfixList.append(opStack.pop())
            opStack.push(token)

    while not opStack.isEmpty():
        postfixList.append(opStack.pop())
    return " ".join(postfixList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('data.in', 'r') as infile:
        data = infile.read().replace('\n', '')
    print(data)
    b = infixToPostfix( data )
```

Input file:

```
"2 + 3 * 5"
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please?

Comment: Also show the input file and your actual error.

Comment: now it should be good. sorry for this but it's the first time i post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file has quotes which are not necessary. Either remove them from the file, or handle quotes in the code. Reading from the file already gives you a string.